# Missing UPN in claim using v2.0 endpoint

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, claims

I have set up a project like the following example from Microsoft where I have a native application requesting access to a web api using the v2.0 endpoint: https://github.com/azureadquickstarts/appmodelv2-nativeclient-dotnet

I have managed to sign in successfully to AAD by using an account registered in that AAD and not a Microsoft account. I do receive a list of claims. However, the upn claim and the email claim are missing. I am using jwt.ms to analyze the claim and this is the info I am receiving from the claim:

```
{
   "typ": "JWT",
   "alg": "RS256",
   "kid": "1LTMzakihiRla_8z2BEJVXeWMqo"
}.{
   "aud": "Client ID/ App ID",
   "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/v2.0",
   "iat": 1534758037,
   "nbf": 1534758037,
   "exp": 1534761937,
   "aio": "ATQAy/8IAAAA+PZj+5vnrUwDfqTTKNBDcy0Tl7rOztkxzrb9YWXHVlevKwrlsGBP/gYAvL4bwr2G",
   "azp": "Client ID/ App ID",
   "azpacr": "0",
   "e_exp": 262800,
   "name": "xxx yyy",
   "oid": "9cc37e1d-0490-4cf4-9bb8-c872899dee91",
   "preferred_username": "test@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com",
   "scp": "access_as_user",
   "sub": "2l0nasrd8QbBpiEu1RGLFCavj3SzTzizIgmKAiMbdU0",
   "tid": "tenantid",
   "uti": "HG2cIi_MGUyBxBl6MzFPAA",
   "ver": "2.0"
}.[Signature]
```

I can't figure out why I am not getting the UPN in the claim. I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Which scopes are you specifying when authenticating the user?

Comment: I am using the default scope:  "access_as_user"

Comment: Could you try adding `openid` and `profile` to the scopes? Not sure if it adds those by default but v2 doesn't return all user data unless you ask for it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you are also requesting the `openid` and the `profile` scopes. 
Information on what scopes give what information in the individual claims can be found in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-id-and-access-tokens) with some basic overview info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent)
I downloaded the sample you referenced. In the App.config file, I changed the scope key to /access_as_user openid profile email" /> and ran it the code. This results in getting the preferred_username claim - "The primary username that represents the user in the v2.0 endpoint. It could be an email address, phone number, or a generic username without a specified format. Its value is mutable and might change over time. The profile scope is required in order to receive this claim."
The `openid`, `profile` and `email` scopes are part of the well-known scopes in the V2 endpoints, discussed in the [Azure AD developer's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc).  To view those well-known scopes you can go to the URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Where `{tenant}` can be replaced with
    common  = Users with both a personal Microsoft account and a work or school account from Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) can sign in to the application.
    organizations  = Only users with work or school accounts from Azure AD can sign in to the application.
    consumers = Only users with a personal Microsoft account can sign in to the application.
    tenantGUID or tenantName = (your specific Azure AD tenant id or name - i.e. contoso.onmicrosoft.com) users of a single tenant can access the application. Either the friendly domain name of the Azure AD tenant or the tenant's GUID identifier can be used.

Going to the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` URL you will get JSON that shows those scopes available there under the `scopes_supported` section:

```
"scopes_supported": 
[
  "openid",
  "profile",
  "email",
  "offline_access"
],
```

Those four scopes are special scopes to the v2 endpoint and therefore when you request them, you do not need to see what application or service principal those scopes are accessing. They are global in a way to the v2 endpoint, hence when you request them, you request them as `openid profile email offline_access` no application identifier should be used for those scopes.

Comment: I have added the openid, profile and email scope in the app registration portal but I get the same claim. I have added the scopes under the web api and I have also tried to add the scopes under Microsoft Graph Permissions.

Comment: How are you calling the authorization endpoint? Is this an SDK?

Comment: This is the code used in order to acquire the token: app = new PublicClientApplication(clientId, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0", TokenCacheHelper.GetUserCache());     result = await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes, app.Users.FirstOrDefault());     where Scopes = "api://appid/access_as_user api://appid/openid api://appid/email"

Comment: I downloaded the sample you referenced.  In the `App.config` file, I changed the scope key to `<add key="TodoListServiceScope" value="api://<api_guid>/access_as_user openid profile email" />` and ran it the code.  This results in getting the `preferred_username` claim - "The primary username that represents the user in the v2.0 endpoint. It could be an email address, phone number, or a generic username without a specified format. Its value is mutable and might change over time. The profile scope is required in order to receive this claim."

Comment: I was already getting the preferred_username in the claim with access_as_user scope only. I don't know why it seems to be ignoring the rest of the scopes.

Comment: I have replaced the scopes as you suggested: <add key="TodoListServiceScope" value="api://appid/access_as_user openid profile email" /> but I am still getting the same claim.

Comment: that comes down to the `supported claims` in the v2.0 available in the well-known URL `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` :  `"claims_supported": 
[
"sub",
"iss",
"cloud_instance_name",
"cloud_instance_host_name",
"cloud_graph_host_name",
"msgraph_host",
"aud",
"exp",
"iat",
"auth_time",
"acr",
"nonce",
"preferred_username",
"name",
"tid",
"ver",
"at_hash",
"c_hash",
"email"
],`

Comment: The `preferred_username` is the `OpenID Connect` standard that Microsoft is using in the v2 endpoint.  [OpenID Connect Standard Claims](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid the preferred_username is not unique so I cannot use it in my case. From what I have read I think I will need to make a request to the graph api to get the upn but I cannot find a suitable way to do this. Do you know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Thank you for all this information, it's useful, but even after adding `['user.read', 'openid', 'profile']` I am still unable to get the user principal name (upn).

Comment: @SSHThis have you updated your application manifest to accept version 2 tokens? Also, there are optional claims available now since the time of this post. The newer functionality and [optional claims are available on the Docs site here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims)

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a request explicitly for UPN and Email. In v1.0 endpoint they are returned by default but because v2.0 wanted smaller tokens, they have made it optional. Go through the following links and hopefully your problem will be solved.
Why you have to request for UPN and email claims
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims
How to add optional claims in application manifest
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest