# How to get User Principal Name from Microsoft Azure AD Login Process

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am using @azure/msal-angular to login a user. I have provided the following "consentScopes":

```
['openid', 'email', 'profile']
```

The Login Redirect process works, as it redirects me to a "https://login.microsoftonline.com" URL, and the "scope" parameter looks like this:

```
&scope=email%20openid%20profile
```

So far so good, I login, get redirected back to my site, then I print out the "getUser()" method provided by the MSAL Service (obfuscated in case of sensitive values):

```
displayableId: "D...Mm"
name: "Mo....as"
identityProvider: "htt...0"
userIdentifier: "OG....5"
idToken:
aud: "ca...20"
iss: "htt....0"
iat: 1..83
nbf: 15..83
exp: 15...83
acct: 0
aio: "42dg....R/XQoA"
auth_time: 159...282
email: "DM.....com"
name: "Mo....as"
nonce: "7bc....d95d"
oid: "8e8f....fc3"
platf: "1"
preferred_username: "DMol....om"
sub: "j0KKHsU....WMEB_H3fyU"
tid: "98f7abd.....6fbd5f9"
uti: "Eu4y.....cMAAA"
ver: "2.0"
```

There is no UPN value provided here. After research I have found that the 1.0 version returned UPN by default.

I found this useful question, with lots of information, but it doesn't actually answer the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57692622/1079602

The following is a screenshot from the Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims)

[image: Microsoft doc image]

It specifically states that the "profile" scope should return a "upn" value. I don't this is a problem with the @azure/msal-angular package, because the Login URL is being generated correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you got is the `id token`, it doesn't include the `upn` claim, see the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens).

The upn claim will be included in the access token, to get the access token, you could refer to the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=angular#acquire-a-token-with-a-pop-up-window), which uses the [Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow).

```
// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
        clientId: 'Enter_the_Application_Id_Here',
      }
    },
    {
      popUp: !isIE,
      consentScopes: [
        'user.read',
        'openid',
        'profile',
      ],
      protectedResourceMap: [
        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
      ]
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When you use this flow to get the access token, you will find the token is `ver: "1.0"`, because the version of the token is decided by the resource(in your case, Microsoft Graph), not the client, refer to the reason [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens):

[image]

---

**Test:**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=xxxxx
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
&scope=email openid profile
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand for 2.0 and oauth, UPN is an option claim, that you must specify in your app registration either in the manifest or in the token configuration-> add optional claim. That's on top of the profile scope if I understand correctly, I think profile scope gives the oidc access to those extra information but does not necessarily include it in the claims.

I could be wrong of course, but I don't see where it states that profile will return upn value in the token?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-groups-optional-claims